# Weird encrypting trying to import sample from dta file using perl in R

Tags: r

I am trying to import an 1% sample of a very large (67 GB) dta file because I don't have enough RAM to import the whole dataset:

```
path <- "/my_path.dta"
data <- system(paste("perl -ne 'print if (rand() < .1)'",path), intern=TRUE)
```

But the resulting object is a character with no variables and weird encrypting, instead of a dataframe:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I would not assume _encryption_, but I think that's more semantic than really helpful. I'm assuming that the `.dta` file is [STATA's format](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000471.shtml), which means it is a _binary_ format, so randomly selecting _lines_ from the file is both incorrect (binary formats are not always line-oriented) and likely a corrupting sampling.